# Excel VBA zooming range

Tags: vba, excel, zooming

```
If Target.Address = "$D$2:$F$861" Then

    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
    [A5000] = "zoomed"
ElseIf [A5000] = "zoomed" Then
     'Otherwise set the zoom to original
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 70
    [A5000].ClearContents 
End If
```

In the above code  `If Target.Address = "$D$2:$F$861" Then` does not work.

I want to zoom in while user choses D2:F861.

When i type single cell adress like `$A$2` it works.

Please help me that when user choose this area zoom changes to 100% otherwise it stays 70% or the other option it stays what user sets

---

It is not actually range comparison. It added new value even when you choose from dropdown list with comma to desired cell.

However, if we dont get bigger font from dropdown list. I want to add some code to zoom while choose the cells which have dropdown lists.

---

It is full code below:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
Dim strVal As String
Dim i As Long
Dim lCount As Long
Dim Ar As Variant
On Error Resume Next
Dim lType As Long
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler



 If Target.Address = "$D$2:$F$861" Then

    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
    [A5000] = "zoomed"
ElseIf [A5000] = "zoomed" Then
     'Otherwise set the zoom to original
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 70
    [A5000].ClearContents
End If

lType = Target.Validation.Type
If lType = 3 Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
newVal = Target.Value
Application.Undo
oldVal = Target.Value
Target.Value = newVal





    If oldVal = "" Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        If newVal = "" Then
            'do nothing
        Else
            On Error Resume Next
            Ar = Split(oldVal, ", ")
            strVal = ""
            For i = LBound(Ar) To UBound(Ar)
                Debug.Print strVal
                Debug.Print CStr(Ar(i))
                If newVal = CStr(Ar(i)) Then
                    'do not include this item
                    strVal = strVal
                    lCount = 1
                Else
                    strVal = strVal & CStr(Ar(i)) & ", "
                End If
            Next i
            If lCount > 0 Then
                Target.Value = Left(strVal, Len(strVal) - 2)
            Else
                Target.Value = strVal & newVal
            End If
        End If
    End If

End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What does "Does not work" mean? Are you getting an error? Have you debugged and this condition is never met?

Comment: `If Not Intersect(Target, range("$D$2:$F$861")) is nothing then`

Comment: @SJR : I tough of it too, but this will only says if Target is in the range.

Comment: @TimWilkinson does not work means i debugged but nothing happens there is no error also

Comment: `If Target = Me.Range("$D$2:$F$861") Then` should work. Even if I don't really see the point of that zoom...

Comment: @SJR if user choose this area it should zoom

Comment: @R3uK - ah yes, it was a reflex reaction, perhaps have to check the extent of a selected range?

Comment: @O.k : Can you add your full code for this? I guess the whole `Worksheet_SelectionChange` sub.

Comment: @SJR : I proposed a simple range comparaison, that should work even if the whole point of the code is beyond me!^^

Comment: @R3uK - I think the current code would work if it were in a selectionchange rather than change event.

Answer (score 0):

To know if `Target` is inside the desired Range, you can test it with this :
`If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("$D$2:$F$861")) Is Nothing Then`

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
Dim strVal As String
Dim i As Long
Dim lCount As Long
Dim Ar As Variant
On Error Resume Next
Dim lType As Long
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler


MsgBox "In event"

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("$D$2:$F$861")) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "In range"
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
    Me.[A5000] = "zoomed"
Else
    If Me.[A5000] = "zoomed" Then
         'Otherwise set the zoom to original
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 70
        Me.[A5000].ClearContents
    Else
    End If
End If


MsgBox "Check validation"
lType = Target.Validation.Type
If lType = 3 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    newVal = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    oldVal = Target.Value
    Target.Value = newVal
    If oldVal = vbNullString Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        If newVal = vbNullString Then
            'do nothing
        Else
            On Error Resume Next
            Ar = Split(oldVal, ", ")
            strVal = vbNullString
            For i = LBound(Ar) To UBound(Ar)
                Debug.Print strVal
                Debug.Print CStr(Ar(i))
                If newVal = CStr(Ar(i)) Then
                    'do not include this item
                    strVal = strVal
                    lCount = 1
                Else
                    strVal = strVal & CStr(Ar(i)) & ", "
                End If
            Next i
            If lCount > 0 Then
                Target.Value = Left(strVal, Len(strVal) - 2)
            Else
                Target.Value = strVal & newVal
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If Target = Me.Range("$D$2:$F$861") Then command line return error. Run time error "13" Type Mismatch error.However, thanks for whole code simplification and division.

Comment: @O.k : Ok, so you'd have to stick with the `.Address`, give the edit a try! ;)

Comment: .Address did not work. But, worksheet change is working, zoom is not working

Comment: @O.k Do you have an error? Or just nothing is happening? Did you select the whole range?

Comment: No, i've got no error but i dont select whole range. All i want to do is if i select any cell from this range code should zoom not required to select whole range.

Comment: Mkay, that could have been clearer from the start if you said it like this!^^ Let me a second to edit! ;)

Comment: Sorry for that i did not mention this point :( But, i tried to select the range you've written in the code. But, code could not zoom as well. Also, please edit the code like "if user selects the cell which is not located in this range, code dont change the zoom ratio. Therefore, when user selects another cell code let him/her arrange zoom manually

Comment: @O.k : NP, this should do! ;)

Comment: :) now neither zoom nor data selection with comma does not work :( without error also :( Code runs but do nothing :(

Comment: Haha okay but everything is same. Code runs but nothing happens even seperation with comma :(

Comment: @O.k : I've added messages to see in which parts of the code you are going, let me know which one pop up! ;)

Comment: First of all, code runs when i decided to choose a value from dropdown lists which are located in my range(D2:F861). One note that, code zoomed after "In Range" writings but, it zoomed out back to 70% before "Check Validation" . I think it enters both if not and elseif. The other thing is that i think code should have 2 separate function(or what is called in VBA) one operates for that if user selects a cell from range it must zoom in or nothing happens. The other one is for arranging dropdown lists. I mean they should operate independent from each other.

Comment: Also, i can send you the original file. You should see what i want to do

Comment: @O.k : I've updated the code to avoid zooming out right after zooming in. As for the separation, you can create another sub for data validation with a range argument and call it from inside the event with `Target` as parameter. Try it and ask another question if you get stuck! (you can poke me here with the new question's link if you want) ;)

Comment: my friend, the code you've last edited runs similar to last version. It zoom in and out. Also, i don't have much information about making 2 different sub. Can you make it for me please ?